# How to get the full width of a column in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

So the parent container seems to be occupying the full width as expected but the ones in the columns seems cut off because the column width looks like it only fits-content

how do I make the column width 100% of its parent or is there any other approach

```
Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 10.0),
              alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
              child: Column(

                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[


                    Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                      child: Text('data')
                    ),


                    Container(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
                      child: Text('data')
                    )
                  // ],)

                ],
                )
            ),
```

Comment: You can pass `width:double.infinity` to the container and that should do the job.

Comment: you can use property of container 
    width : double.infinity

Comment: you can say Container width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1 Then you always have the max screen size no matter which device. With double.infinity sometimes you get weird effects if your UI is getting more complex

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [LayoutBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) to fetch the parent widget's size.

```dart
Container(
  child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
    debugPrint('Container width: ${constraints.maxWidth}');
    return Column(); 
  }),
),
```

If you'd like to fetch the entire screen's dimension, you can use [MediaQuery](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html).

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
  if (screenSize.width > layoutSize) {
    return Widget();
  } else {
    // return Widget if size doesn't match
    return Widget(); 
  }
}
```